# I don't know where to catch this error: Access to the port is denied

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, serial-port

I'm using a serial port with a Serial Object and sometimes I get this error.

`UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the port is denied.`

with a stack trace of:

```
   at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Finalize()
```

It doesn't occur at any line of code (within my code at least) so I'm not sure how to trap it. I figure what is happening is the serial (via USB) port is being physically unplugged/disconnected for a split second and is throwing everything into whack.

I can click `Continue` on the error which I'm debugging and everything is fine. Communication with the serial device is flawless otherwise. But when the program is actually published, deployed and running it gives me several error messages and is all ugly for the user.

How can I trap this error/what can I do to prevent it in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: It could be SerialPort.Open, regarding MSDN it can throw such exception. This mean that port is already opened

Comment: What do JIT error messages have to do with this particular exception?

Comment: @sll The port is definitely open, but, whenever I get the error, seemingly nothing is happening. I.e. I'm not trying to re-open an open port. I guess for all I know the port closed in the background...but that wouldn't make sense because upon clicking continue I can still interact with the device. I'm watching the WndProc messages to see when the user plugs/unplugs the device and I perform port opening/closing when such events occur.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, sorry for the typo. They're just regular errors. They have the phrase "See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box." At the top and I had the phrase in my mind.

Comment: You can't trap this exception nor is there a good workaround for it.  Your customer needs to keep her fingers off the USB connector while the port is opened.  Or find a device whose driver doesn't make the device disappear while it is in use.  .NET 4 has some additional internal workarounds for the problem.

Comment: This is unfortunate news but workable I guess. For future reference, what are the .NET 4 workarounds?

Comment: @HansPassant Why not make the answer into 'answer' so the questions can be closed out?

Comment: @John - because that will make my answer the target for the considerable annoyance experienced by programmers by this behavior.  They do shoot the messenger around here.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same exception and stack trace in my WinForms application when used with a USB-to-serial converter.  I can consistently recreate it by

- creating an instance of SerialPort
- calling SerialPort.Open,
- removing the USB-to-serial converter,
- closing the app (which calls SerialPort.Dispose)

My suspicion is that the exception is being thrown in SerialPort's finalizer.
Others have experienced the same symptoms - see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/8b02d5d0-b84e-447a-b028-f853d6c6c690).

To work around I followed the recommendation of Kuno and KyferEz (from link above) to implement my own ExtSerialPort.  This inherits SerialPort, overrides the Dispose method and (using reflection) disposes the SerialPort's internalSerialStream.

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class ExtSerialPort
    Inherits SerialPort

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.new()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal portName As String)
        MyBase.New(portName)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

        Dim mytype As Type = GetType(SerialPort)
        Dim field As Reflection.FieldInfo = mytype.GetField("internalSerialStream", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim stream As Object = field.GetValue(Me)

        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                stream.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If

        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

End Class
```